# In Entity Framework, what to use instead of 'contains' in where clause,since where clause is affecting the performance of the query

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda, entity-framework-6

I have a function in which contains function is used at many places to check whether a user id contains in list of ids(List ) or  not. And for checking this 'contains' is used , but then using this affects the performance of the method. So is there any other option for 'contains'?

Comment: The contains method itself is not a root of your problem. The query performance is. Try writing query in sql directly figure out how to make it perform better and then try to figure out EF linq for it.

Comment: Whar is it, that you are using `Contains()` with? Numbers, Strings? Could you show us some code?

Comment: Generally within Linq Where clause it is used Any(). For example: DB.Users.Where( x => ListIds.Any(id => id = x.Id)) returns all users whose id it is contained in ListIds.

Comment: data.AssignedChecklistItems = _assignedChecklistItems.Where(x => currentChecklistItemIds.Contains(x.OriginalChecklistItemID) && !x.DeactivatedDateTime.HasValue && currentChecklistsIds.Contains(x.AssignedChecklistID)).ToList();                                     In the above code "currentChecklistItemIds" is the list of IDs.